# json to dataframe in python: some fields don't convert to dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe

I have one json file. I opened it with pd.read_json and then whem parsing to a geodtaframe just some fields are considered. Nut some are not. When I open it on QGIS for instance there are multiple columns that I cannot convert to geodataframe.

So my file is called PT:

```
PT = pd.read_json('PT.json')
PT

    type    features
0   FeatureCollection   {'id': 'osm-w96717521', 'type': 'Feature', 'pr...
1   FeatureCollection   {'id': 'osm-w96850552', 'type': 'Feature', 'pr...
2   FeatureCollection   {'id': 'osm-r1394361', 'type': 'Feature', 'pro...
```

and for different PT lines I have different fields:
So for instance for:

```
PT['features'][0]
{'id': 'osm-w96717521',
 'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'height': 24,
  'heightSrc': 'manual',
  'levels': 8,
  'date': 201804},
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[-9.151539, 38.725054],
    [-9.15148, 38.724906],
    [-9.151281, 38.724918],
    [-9.151254, 38.724867],
    [-9.151142, 38.724699],
    [-9.150984, 38.724783],
    [-9.151081, 38.724918],
    [-9.151152, 38.725076],
    [-9.151539, 38.725054]]]}}
```

and for:

```
 PT['features'][100000]

{'id': 'osm-w556092901',
 'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'date': 201801, 'orient': 95, 'height': 3, 'heightSrc': 'ai'},
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[-9.402381, 38.742663],
    [-9.402342, 38.74261],
    [-9.402215, 38.742667],
    [-9.402281, 38.742706],
    [-9.402381, 38.742663]]]}}
```

it has also the field 'orient'.

When I convert the features dict to each column on a df, for some columns result:

```
df["coordinates"] = nta["features"].apply(lambda row: row["geometry"]["coordinates"])
df
```

but those that do not appear on every line I cannot consider. So for 'levels' or 'orient':

```
df["floors"] = nta["features"].apply(lambda row: row["properties"]["levels"])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [46], line 1
----> 1 df["floors"] = nta["features"].apply(lambda row: row["properties"]["levels"])
(...)
KeyError: 'levels'
```

How can I get all columns contained in feature even if for some values they should be null?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if/else construct like return nan if the key does not exist.

```
import numpy as np

df["floors"] = nta["features"].apply(lambda row: row["properties"]["levels"] if 'levels' in list(row["properties"].keys()) else np.nan)
df["coordinates"] = nta["features"].apply(lambda row: row["geometry"]["coordinates"] if 'coordinates' in list(row["geometry"].keys()) else np.nan)
```